# How to set environment variable without rebooting Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, android, environment-variables

Problem: During Android development, in order to add ADB path to environment variable; I did following things:

`gedit /etc/environment` - Added my desired path in the file such as `:/media/Software/00.AndroidLinux/ADT/sdk/platform-tools`

What I noticed is that adding path to the file has no effect to `$PATH` until I reboot my Ubuntu.

My question is: How can I add path to `/etc/environment` variable, so that I can work with my modified `$PATH`, and without restarting Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking you can't since that file is only read on login, by pam_env. You can however source it in your current shell to read in the values.

```
$ . /etc/environment
```

Answer (score 9):

You can add to your $PATH variable directly like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/the/dir/you/want/to/add
```

Then, edit /etc/environment.

An alternate method would be to still export as I showed above, but then to add the entry to your ~/.bashrc file (if using BASH shell).

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/the/dir/you/want/to/add" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

EDIT: Exporting your $PATH in your ~/.bashrc file rather than /etc/environment keeps you from needing to elevate permissions to edit a "global" (system) config file and also keeps other users (if you have any on your system) from having that path auto-added on account creation.